# Org-mode: embed links to info files

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I maintain a diary (internal blog containing thoughts to remember) in org-mode, and sometimes, as i study Emacs, i store learned skills and tricks with references to info files.

Currently i do the following. I open the needed info file, press <kbd>c</kbd> to copy current node name, press <kbd>< s TAB</kbd> - that is an [easy template](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html) which unwraps into a [src-block](http://orgmode.org/manual/Working-With-Source-Code.html). Then i add lisp expression and paste node name and finally the link looks like this:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(info "(org) Properties and Columns")
#+end_src
```

When i need to view the info file, i put cursor after lisp sexp and press <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> (eval-last-sexp).

This process is tedious and inelegant. What is the best way to embed links to info files in org-mode?

**Edit:** I've found how one can add links to info nodes. Org-mode manual on [External links](http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html) describes these equivalent methods using links:

```
[[info:org#Tags]]
[[elisp:(info "(org) Tags")]]
```

With the first variant i'm not sure how to automatically transform `(org) Tags` in `org#Tags`. How can i further simplify this process?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You do it as in any of the supported link types (see the ["Handling
links"](http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html) section in the manual). In the info file, you say `M-x org-store-link`,
(bind it to `C-c l` as suggested in the manual) and then in your org
file, you insert the link with `C-c C-l`. There you just have to
select the link to your info file from the list of stored links.

Answer (score 2):

`org-store-link` says "Cannot link to a buffer which is not visiting a file" when visiting an Info page because Info sets the `buffer-name` to `*info*` and the `buffer-file-name` to `nil`. To work around this, the community contributed example of how to add linking to man pages (http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html) can be modified slightly:

```
;; Modified version of contrib/lisp/org-man.el; see
;; (http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html#Adding-hyperlink-types)
(require 'org)

(org-add-link-type "info" 'org-info-open)
(add-hook 'org-store-link-functions 'org-info-store-link)

(defcustom org-info-command 'info
  "The Emacs command to be used to display an info page."
  :group 'org-link
  :type '(choice (const info)))

(defun org-info-open (path)
  "Visit the infopage on PATH.
   PATH should be a topic that can be thrown at the info command."
  (funcall org-info-command path))

(defun org-info-store-link ()
  "Store a link to an info page."
  (when (memq major-mode '(Info-mode))
    ;; This is a info page, we do make this link
    (let* ((page (org-info-get-page-name))
           (link (concat "info:" page))
           (description (format "Infopage for %s" page)))
      (org-store-link-props
       :type "info"
       :link link
       :description description))))

(defun org-info-get-page-name ()
  "Extract the page name from Info in a hackish way."
  ;; This works for `Info-mode'.
  ;; Hackity-hack: copy the node name into the kill ring.
  (Info-copy-current-node-name)
  ;; Just return the kill.
  (current-kill 0))

(provide 'org-info)
```

The important bit is near the end: since the info node name is not directly accessible (not that I could easily find), we can work around it by calling `Info-copy-current-node-name` to put it in the `kill-ring`, then return the first entry in the `kill-ring` (which should be the just inserted node name).

Comment: Note that this information was true in 2013 but has not been true since at least 2017. `org-store-link` now handles Info files correctly without external ancillary functions.

Comment: If you're reading this after 2017 and `org-store-link` still doesn't seem to handle Info buffers correctly by default, make sure that `'ol-info` is in `org-modules`. At least in 2021, Doom emacs omits it by default, which can be remedied with `(after! org (add-to-list 'org-modules 'ol-info))`.

Answer (score 2):

The step that should work
- go to info node you need then press just 'c' (node-name will be
  entry to kill ring)
- on your org source-file go to point you need to insert the link
  press C-c,C-l
- press Tab then select elisp: from prompted buffer shown (or any kind
  of link you need).Now your prompt in mini-buffer say elisp:
- entry this context after that ':' (info "^") ,let ^ be your
  node-name yank back by C-y
- press Ret ,then you'll be ask for some description just fill it with
  your own. Now you are done with it ,but still don't know what happen
  really.
- M-x,visibility-mode,And there how to write that content manually and
  we are now came to conclusion that "%20" must be replace every
  occurence of space in the context.
  eg.==> do it yourself ,see it yourself 
- switch back your visibility-mode
GoodLuck